# Scrape data table using xpath in R

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping

I am fairly familiar with R, but have 0 experience with web scraping. I had looked around and cannot seem to figure out why my web scraping is "failing." Here is my code including the URL I want to scrape (the ngs-data-table to be specific):

```
library(rvest)
webpage <- read_html("https://nextgenstats.nfl.com/stats/rushing/2020/REG/1#yards")
tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, xpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/main/div/div/div[3]')
#also attempted using this Xpath '//*[@id="stats-rushing-view"]/div[3]' but neither worked
tbls
```

I am not receiving any errors with the code but I am receiving:

```
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

I know this isn't a ton of code, I have tried multiple different xpaths as well. I **know** I will eventually need more code to be more specific for web-scraping, but I figured even the code above would at least begin to point me in the right direction? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is stored as JSON.  Here is a method to download and process that file.

```
library(httr)

#URL for week 6 data
url <- "https://nextgenstats.nfl.com/api/statboard/rushing?season=2020&seasonType=REG&week=6"

#create a user agent 
ua <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"

#download the information
content <-httr::GET(url, verbose() , user_agent(ua), add_headers(Referer =  "https://nextgenstats.nfl.com/stats/rushing/2020/REG/1"))
answer <-jsonlite::fromJSON(content(content, as = "text") ,flatten = TRUE)
answer$stats
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Just out of curiosity, how did you know it was stored as JSON?

Comment: Many pages such as this one are dynamically created using javascript with the data stored as an external table.  It is a matter of using the "network" tab of the browser's developer tools and looking at the "XHR" files.

Answer (score 0):

The content of that table is generated dynamically: check it by saving the page from your browser (or, with your code, `write_html(webpage,'test.html')`) and then opening the saved file. So you probably can't capture it with `rvest`. Browser simulation packages like `RSelenium` will solve the problem.